# Generate application metadata file for ADFS configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, adfs

I've followed the steps on http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/ to create a new MVC application using ADFS to authenticate my users. Now the team behind the ADFS configuration needs the application metadata file to allow the application to connect the ADFS.

How can I generate this metadata file?

Answer (score 0):

It normally "lives" at /FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml in your STS website.  If you used a standard solution like thinktecture then that is the case.  Otherwise, you can generate it yourself using the .Net classes in System.IdentityModel.Metadata.  You can find some inspiration at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.WsFederation/blob/25a2101f9bfe78e4ec856eb15c9bf19a9a9b256c/source/WsFederationPlugin/WsFederationController.cs and related classes.

Comment: But this on the client or server side? On server I have this url, but my application after adding the reference to ADFS via Visual Studio 2013 doesn't have.

Comment: This is on the server (the STS).  The client doesn't have this.  The client generally *consumes* this data (p.e. in Owin this metadata document is all that is needed to configure your client)

Comment: The client app can have a version of FederationMetadata.xml as well; at least our IDP requested one. I was able to generate it for a Web Forms application using WIP and some custom code. Haven't found an MVC solution yet. The only relevant data in it (as far as I can see) is the realm URI. Just mentioning it since this is the top hit on Google.